# Slow Buffer.concat

Tags: node.js, performance, buffer

When I read a 16MB file in pieces of 64Kb, and do `Buffer.concat` on each piece, the latter proves to be incredibly slow, takes a whole 4s to go through the lot.

Is there a better way to concatenate a buffer in Node.js?

Node.js version used: 7.10.0, under Windows 10 (both are 64-bit).

---

This question is asked while researching the following issue: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1286, which affects a large audience.

The PostgreSQL driver reads large `bytea` columns in chunks of 64Kb, and then concatenates them. We found out that calling `Buffer.concat` is the culprit behind a huge loss of performance in such examples.

Comment: Why do you have to read in 64KB pieces?  In either case, it shouldn't take 4 seconds to do that.  Can you narrow this code down?

Comment: @Brad I've just added an explanation.

Comment: Push each piece into an array and use `Buffer.concat()` on the whole thing together. O(n) instead of O(n²) time to copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than concatenating every time (which creates a new buffer each time), just keep an array of all of your buffers and concat at the end.

`Buffer.concat()` can take a whole list of buffers.  Then it's done in one operation.  https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength

Comment: This strategy only works if you are writing all of your data up front before reading it. If you are reading from the stream as it's being written, then you either need a strategy for pulling out the correct data from the array of buffers (which can get messy), or you need to grow the buffer in a performant way (traditional solution). This article has one explanation of buffer doubling: https://crntaylor.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/optimal-memory-reallocation-and-the-golden-ratio/

Comment: @MatthewAmato You can read from your array of buffers at any time.  Since the size of the buffers are uniform in length, it's actually trivial to pull out what chunk is needed, should you actually need to read from it before its done.  Given that the question is asking about concatenating an entire 16MB chunk, it seems that waiting until all the pieces are present is what they're trying to do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you read from a file and know the size of that file, then you can pre-allocate the final buffer. Then each time you get a chunk of data, you can simply write it to that large 16Mb buffer.

```
// use the "unsafe" version to avoid clearing 16Mb for nothing
let buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(file_size)

let pos = 0
file.on('data', (chunk) => {
    buf.fill(chunk, pos, pos + chunk.length)
    pos += chunk.length
})

if(pos != file_size) throw new Error('Ooops! something went wrong.')
```

The main difference with @Brad's code sample is that you're going to use 16Mb + size of one chunk (roughly) instead of 32Mb + size of one chunk.

Also, each chunk has a header, various pointers, etc. so you are not unlikely to use 33Mb or even 34Mb... that's a lot more RAM. The amount of RAM copied is otherwise the same. That being said, it could be that Node starts reading the next chunk while you copy so it could make it transparent. When done in one large chunk in the `'end'` event, you're going to have to wait for the `contact()` to complete while doing nothing else in parallel.

---

In case you are receiving an HTTP `POST` and are reading it. Remember that you get a `Content-Length` parameter so you also have the length in that case and can pre-allocate the entire buffer before reading the data.

Comment: Just beware of blindly trusting `Content-Length` from HTTP clients.  They could send you some massive value and instantly crash your server.  Or, `Content-Length` doesn't have to actually be accurate.  This is a very common vulnerability.

Comment: I first test for a max. size and throw immediately if off limit and I verify what I received vs what was specified in `Content-Length` once the upload finishes. If wrong, again I throw. Finally, I verify the data receive for tainted data. So I should be covered for 99% of the potential problems in that area...